# Saving a MATLAB surface object as an image

Tags: image, matlab, save, surface

I can generate a MATLAB surface object (using `h=pcolor(X,Y,C)`) and I would like to save just that surface object in an image format (`png`, `tiff`, ...) without any visible background.

The surface is elliptical and not rectangular so I want to see just the ellipse, without white background, axes, labels, ticks, frame, menus, etc.

I want to use it as an overlay on Google Earth so the entity may be rectangular, as long as the parts outside the ellipse are transparent.

MATLAB and its user community seem to offer a number of ways to save images but I have not yet found one that saves just the surface object. Any solutions or even suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: btw, color can't take a Z argument (3rd dimension) but a C one (color).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `export_fig` tool from the matlab's FEX ([www](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)) to export the figure with a transparent background (not all the image formats are supported).

To get rid of the axes and just plot the surface, you can do

```
set(gca,'Visible','off')
```

Comment: Yes... this is a solution. I also found that "axis off" was sufficient to eliminate axes.